# property not found mapping combining streams with RxJS in angular

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular-observable

Hi I have this two streams with Ofertas and concursos

```
ofertas$ = this.dataService.getOfertas();
concursos$ = this.dataService.getConcursos();

ofertasConOrganismos$ = forkJoin([
 this.ofertas$,
 this.concursos$
]);

ngOnInit(): void {
this.ofertasConOrganismos$
  .subscribe(item => console.log(item));
```

}

[image: streams]

In Ofertas[] each Oferta has organismoId Property that I need to fill with the relationed value en Concurso[] that has this property too

[image: organismoId]

[image: concurso]

But when I try this

```
ofertasConOrganismos$ = forkJoin([
this.ofertas$,
this.concursos$
])
.pipe(
  map(([ofertas, concursos]) =>
    ofertas.map(oferta => ({
      ...oferta,
      organismoId: concursos.find(c => c.id == oferta.concursoId).organismoId
    }) as Oferta))
);
```

I get this error

[image: error]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: From the `Array#find()` docs: _"If no values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned"_. Which most probably means there are cases in your arrays where the `c.id == oferta.concursoId` returns `false`. Check the result from `find()` function for `undefined` before trying to access the `.organismoId` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is with "concursos.find(c => c.id == oferta.concursoId)" that is undefined - the "find()" method didn't find anything so you cannot retrieve ".organismoId" parameter on undefined object. You can use following optional operator syntax (with the question mark) in order to avoid the error:

```
map(([ofertas, concursos]) =>
ofertas.map(oferta => ({
  ...oferta,
  organismoId: concursos.find(c => c.id == oferta.concursoId)?.organismoId
}) as Oferta))
```